# Sinon mock: check args of 2nd call only

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, mocking, sinon

I'm testing a function that will make 2 calls to a mongo database, each one with different arguments. The function is called 'saveAchProgress' and will make 2 'updateOne' requests to db.

I'm using a mock cause I need to spy the function AND block the db calls at he same time (not connected to db during unit tests).

I would like to check the arguments but only for the second db call

I can easily manage to check calls 1 and 2 are properly made:

```
               it('should update if value >= achNumber', async function (): Promise<void> {
                mock.expects('updateOne').twice().returns('foo');
                await achievementsServiceFunctions.saveAchProgress(1, 1);
                mock.verify();
            });
```

However, when I check the arguments, I get an error with the arguments of the first call.

```
            it('should update game with right arguments: collection', async function (): Promise<void> {
                mock.expects('updateOne').withArgs('game', sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any).returns('foo');
                await achievementsServiceFunctions.saveAchProgress(1, 1);
                mock.verify();
            });
```

I know sinon mock have their own way of check stuff but I couldn't find anything fitting my needs in sinon documentation. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sinon [Mocks](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.4.8/mocks/) throw on any call that is not explicitly expected. You're only setting up the second call, but not the first, so the first (which has the wrong arguments) throws.

I've never really used the Mock api in sinon, so I could be wrong, but I don't believe what you're trying to do is possible. It is easy, however, with [Stubs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.4.8/stubs/) and standalone [assertions](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.4.8/assertions/).

Assuming `obj` is the thing you're currently sending to `sinon.mock` to create your `mock` variable:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    sinon.stub(obj, 'updateOne').returns('foo);
});

afterEach(function() {
    obj.updateOne.restore();
});

it('should update game with right arguments: collection', async function() {
    await achievementsServiceFunctions.saveAchProgress(1, 1);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(obj.updateOne.secondCall, 'game');
});
```

Btw, `withArgs` allows additional args after the specified one(s), so you don't need the `sinon.match.any` matchers. You'd only need those if you used `withExactArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. Doing the following helped me:

Sinon Mocks set the expectations even before the function is actually called.

So instead of having  `mock.expects('updateOne').twice()`

You can try :

```
mock.expects('updateOne').once().withExactArgs(
  ... YOUR EXPECTED ARGS FOR THE FIRST CALL
);

mock.expects('updateOne').once().withExactArgs(
  ... YOUR EXPECTED ARGS FOR THE SECOND CALL
);
```

> This way, your first call to "updateOne" expects the args you specify in the first line and your second call to "updateOne" expects the args you specify in the second line.